# How to correctly setup a NSPredicate for a to-many relationship, to check existance object

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I have two Tables TRIP and ALERT

Relationship is 1 to many
A trip can contain 1 or more than 1 alerts,
I want to fetch those trip who contain Alerts

I make fetch request like this, plz asset me Dear

-(NSFetchRequest*) fetchRequestGetTriphavingAlert{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

```
NSEntityDescription *trip = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Trip" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:trip];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"alert == %@",!NULL];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
return fetchRequest;
```

}[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSPrediate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"alert.@count > 0"];
```